# Transitivity in Logic

Tags: logic

I was reading the work of Marvin Minsky on [What makes Mathematics hard to learn?](http://web.media.mit.edu/~minsky/OLPC-1.html) and in the "Bringing Mathematics to Life" chapter there is a question on Logic, here it is:

> If most A’s are B’s, and most B’s are C’s, does this imply that many A’s must also be C’s?

I recognize the `Transitivity concept`, and taking it into consideration one could say the answer is `Yes`. Anyway, I think the answer is `No`, because there could be an `A` that is a `B`, but the `B` is not a `C`. Also by implication rules if hypothesis is `True` and conclusion is `False`, the implication is `False`.

As the author says that:

> Many adults will give the wrong answer to this!

I want to know, what is the correct answer?

Comment: "Most" and "Many" are different words, so it is hard to use transitivity.

Comment: Any single $A$ doesn't help. The question is a question about all A, and some quantity, "most of them," is also a member of $C$.

Comment: Apart from the problem of transitivity, "most" does not imply "many". For example, most current queens regnant are living descendants of Christian IX of Denmark (in fact, 100% of them are), and most living descendants of Christian IX live on Earth (100% of those, too). But still there _aren't_ "many current queens regnant" living on Earth -- in fact there's only two of them.

Comment: "Most" is a *vague* word; see [Vagueness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no", because the A's can still be a minority in B's.

For example, most mathematitians are good at physics, and most people who are good at physics are physicists.

This does not mean most mathematitians are also physicists!

In this example, you can see where the problem is. Yes, most A's (mathematitians) are good at physics. However, most people who are good at physics *are not* mathematitians. So, the behaviour of "most people who are good at physics" can be very different than the behaviour of "most mathematitians".

Comment: Or, for a more likely-true statement, most mathematicians are people, most people have never taken calculus.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Probably a better example.

Answer (score 1):

No. What if all of the A's happen to be B's which are not C's?

$$B = \{ \underbrace{b_1,b_2,b_3}_A,\underbrace{b_4,b_5,b_6,b_7}_C\}$$

In this example, both $A$ and $C$ happen to be contained in $B$, but that need not be the case.